# How to see analysis results of nondefault quality profiles of SonarQube?

Tags: findbugs, sonarqube

I run SonarQube with two quality profiles: First, the default "Sonar Way". Second, "Sonar way with Findbugs.

SQ executes analyses for both profiles successfully and produce html reports in .sonar folder.

But I cannot see the results of analysis of "Sonar way with FindBugs" in dashboard. Even after making that quality profile the default one inside "Quality Profiles" settings and running the analysis from scratch, when I enter the dashboard, SQ still shows the data for the analysis done with the default profile "Sonar Way".

I entered "Issues" link from the sidebar menu. The following url opens: `http://localhost:9000/drilldown/issues/1` At the top of the screen, the profile is stated as "Sonar Way" again.

Is there any way to see the data for another profile than the default profile in dashboard?

Btw, after doing analysis with "Sonar way with Findbugs" the time of last analysis shown in Dashboard does not change.

Comment: Maybe you have set the [Analysis Mode](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Concepts) to *local only*? Check the property `sonar.analysis.mode`. It shouldn't be set. Also, you can set `sonar.verbose` to `true` and show us the resulting log of your second analysis run.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas. Indeed this was the cause of the problem. Uncommenting `sonar.analysis.mode` solved it. If you can write it as answer, I can accept it as the solution. So other people will be able to find it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have set the [Analysis Mode](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Concepts) to *local only*? Check the property `sonar.analysis.mode`. It shouldn't be set.

For further troubleshooting, you can set `sonar.verbose` to `true` and produce a more detailed log of your second analysis run.